# SUM mysql function

Tags: mysql, select, sum

I'm using sum function in my query and it shows all of the column that has the correct sum of selected column but there is one row that gets the sum of all the selected row here is my query

```
SELECT 
  SUM(Local_Amount) as donation, 
  country  
FROM Payments 
GROUP BY country 
ORDER BY donation;
```

The selected data is

```
donation           Country
1,000                France
5,000                Panama
13,000              Monaco
```

The selected sum of monaco is 13,000 instead of 7,000 it gets the sum of all selected row.

Comment: What is your expected and actual result? I can't see what you are asking for.

Comment: The selected data is 

donation           Country
1,000                France
5,000                Panama
13,000              Monaco

The selected sum of monaco is 13,000 instead of 7,000 it gets the sum of all selected row

Comment: Add that to the question, with dummy data, expected result and what you get with your current query to clarify the question. Btw, only last row has such problem?

Comment: I tried it in MySQL Fiddle but can't replicate the result, your query works fine for me. `CREATE TABLE Payments
(
  local_amount INT,
  country VARCHAR(40)
  );
  
INSERT INTO Payments (local_amount, country) VALUES(500, 'France');
INSERT INTO Payments (local_amount, country) VALUES(500, 'France');
INSERT INTO Payments (local_amount, country) VALUES(1000, 'Panama');
INSERT INTO Payments (local_amount, country) VALUES(4000, 'Panama');
INSERT INTO Payments (local_amount, country) VALUES(3000, 'Monaco');
INSERT INTO Payments (local_amount, country) VALUES(4000, 'Monaco');`

Comment: I am getting 7000 for Monaco using your query

Comment: what is `local_amount` the data you display in the question has a heading of `donation`. need to see the data before it gets summed.

Comment: Show your table schema, and clarify: Is the data shown the result or the source? In either case, show both the sample data and the result you are getting.

Comment: *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5e42a7f37a4ed42e1ddabb1a20f69435)* data from comment by @lamandy  (not sure where that came from originally)

Comment: Edit your question, not comments. Your text is unintelligible, please clearly say what you mean.